# Maven 3.0.3 - how to check dependency conflict reason

Tags: maven-3

Is there an easy way to check what is the reason of dependency conflict in maven 3.0.3? It was easy with maven 2.x by using debug mode (-X switch). Since maven 3.0.3, -X doesn't show dependencies resolution problems.
Maven just produce conflict info without giving the underlying source reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Maven (>= 3.0.0) I use the [Sonatype m2eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html) with Eclipse or alternative the latest [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) to graphically visualize the dependency tree and therefore solve any conflict problem. Once the Maven project get imported into the IDE open the POM with the 'Maven POM Editor' and see the 'Dependency Hierarchy' and 'Dependency Graph' tabs.
To import the Maven Project, go to File / Import Project / Maven / Existing Maven Projects.
In order to use your recently downloaded Maven 3.X.Y version instead of the default Eclipse-embedded Maven installation, go to Windows / Preferences / Maven / Installations and Add an external Maven home location. Additionally you shall enable the 'Show advanced tabs in the POM editor' in the section Windows / Preferences / Maven / POM Editor.

Comment: Thank you for helpful answer. I sometimes use Sonatype m2eclipse plugin to solve conflict problems, but it is not as clear information like as textual output provided by maven 2.x. I have never used Spring Tool Suite, i will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

For those who use IntelliJ, I recommend [Maven Helper plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper). You have a specific section for conflicts, and it even allow you to *exclude* for resolving conflicts.

In general, you can use `mvn dependency:tree > "output.txt"` and search in the output file the problematic dependency and see what import it.